# How to handle null values in Volley StringRequest

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a response that is returning 2 different sets of values. In each case, one value will **always** be null and the other will **always** contain a value. The problem is that Volley doesn't let me assign a null JSON value or check a JSON value in an if statement. It simply refers to the catch block. I'm trying to do something like:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                //If this is null, it stops here and goes to catch.
                String value1 = obj.getString("value1") 
                String value2 = obj.getString("value2");

                //Can't perform any more code because Value1 is null

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("Log","Your String was null");

            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Log", "Unable to connect to server!");
        }
    });
```

I can't use `throws` due to the way the library is designed and it forces me to put it in a try/catch. Is there anyway at all around this?

**EDIT:** The following Exception is what I am getting:

> org.json.JSONException: No value for value1

Comment: why don't you just test the value of `response`?

Comment: `response` is not the part that's null. The problem is that putting any of my `get` values (in this case `getString`) in a variable will still cause the catch block to execute. Thus, barring me from being able to put it in an if/else.

Comment: I'd love to hear what warranted a downvote. Pretty straightforward question.

Comment: ok, so you are saying that `response` is not null, but there is an exception that results in the following log `"Your String was null"`, but you won't look at the actual exception to figure this out?

Comment: @njzk2 This is test code. Not my actual code, so obviously I've edited much of this code greatly. Unless you wanted to sift through 900+ lines of code. Yes, I have "looked" at the actual exception. I simply did not include it in the test code. My error. If you would like me to post the exception, all you had to do was ask.

Comment: oh. So it is a simple case of reading the documentation to find the method that does what you are looking for.

Comment: @njzk2 From the documentation itself: `The JSONException is thrown by the JSON.org classes when things are amiss.` I don't think it needs to be this difficult. I have read the documentation, made myself aware of what is "amiss" and figured out why the error is occurring as well. The problem is I CANNOT avoid it for my current situation. Which is why I am asking this question.....

Comment: Your exception is `No value for value1`, which means it occurs at the `get("value1")` line. The documentation for `get` says `Returns the value mapped by name, or throws if no such mapping exists.` Fine. Now, if you take the time to look further, you'll find the `has` method, that says `Returns true if this object has a mapping for name.`. So, you can absolutely test `if (obj.has("value1")) { ... }`. Not difficult indeed.

Comment: @njzk2 I was apparently not reading the same page as you were, which led to my confusion. But thank you for your help. I will accept as answer if you post this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [.isNull("key")](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29) method on JSONObject?

Then you can do something like this:

```
String value1 = jsonObject.isNull("value1") ? null : jsonObject.getString("value1");    
String value2 = jsonObject.isNull("value2") ? null : jsonObject.getString("value2");
```

Comment: It's crazy that you have to check before actually getting the value. Why can't it just return null like you would expect it to. That way you don't have to slap these checks over any field that could possibly be null

Answer (score 0):

I just found a shorter solution. the `optGet()` functions.

```
String value1 = jsonObject.optString("value1");    
String value2 = jsonObject.optString("value2");
```

It returns null instead of throwing an error. They exist for each of the types including `optJSONArray()` and `optJSONObject()`.

[Link to Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#opt(java.lang.String))